# Subtracting a calculated value from each member of a set - MDX

Tags: mdx

I have been tasked with replacing some `T-SQL` code currently used in our reporting with it's `MDX` equivalent. I have experience with `T-SQL` but not `MDX`

I'm currently stuck on the following problem:

- We have a list of Stores and their Lost Sales Percentage.
- Each Store's Lost Sales Percentage is compared against a baseline figure for further analysis.
- I need to take the lowest Lost Sales Percentage value of the top quartile as a baseline figure e.g if we have 3 Stores in the top quartile, with Percentage values of 55,50,45, I would need to use 45 as the baseline figure.
- The baseline figure is dynamic and will change depending upon performance of all of the Stores

My question is - How do I subtract the baseline figure from the list of Stores and their Lost Sales Percentage? I've attempted to do this with the following code:

```
WITH Member [Measures].[TopQPer] AS 
  BOTTOMCOUNT(
    TOPPERCENT(
      [Network].[Centre Id].Members, 
      25,
      [Measures].[Lost Sales Conversion Rate SSO]
    ),
    1,
    [Measures].[Lost Sales Conversion Rate SSO]
  )
Member [Measures].[Difference] AS 
  (
    (
      [Network].[Centre Id].Members,
      [Measures].[Lost Sales Conversion Rate SSO]
    ) 
   - [Measures].[TopQPer]
  ), FORMAT_STRING = 'Percent'
SELECT
  [Measures].[Difference] ON Columns,
  [Network].[Centre Id].MEMBERS ON ROWS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.
I would think that

```
WITH Member [Measures].[TopQPer] AS 
            (Tail(TOPPERCENT([Network].[Centre Id].[Centre Id].Members, 
                             25,
                             [Measures].[Lost Sales Conversion Rate SSO]
                            )
                 ).Item(0).Item(0),
             [Measures].[Lost Sales Conversion Rate SSO]
            )
     Member [Measures].[Difference] AS 
            [Measures].[Lost Sales Conversion Rate SSO] - [Measures].[TopQPer]
           ,FORMAT_STRING = 'Percent'
SELECT
            [Measures].[Difference] ON Columns,
            [Network].[Centre Id].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM        [YourCube]
```

delivers what you want.

There is no need to use `Bottomcount(, 1)`. Using `Tail()` instead is more efficient to get the last entry. And as `TopPercent` already delivers the data sorted, we are sure we can just take the last entry.

I use a tuple as the value to use for `[Measures].[TopQPer]`. Hence, as `Tail` (like `BottomCount`, by the way) returns a set, I convert that singe element set to a member by applying `Item(0)` twice. This is actually two different methods: The first is applied on a set, delivering its first tuple, and the second applied on a tuple, returns its first member.

In the definition of the `Difference` measure, you can just subtract your newly defined measure `TopQPer` from `Lost Sales Conversion Rate SSO`. The latter will use the current `[Network].[Centre Id]` from the row header in each cell where it is evaluated, while `TopQPer`, as the current context of this hierarchy is overwritten in its definition, will be constant across all center Ids.

Finally, note that I used `[Network].[Centre Id].[Centre Id].Members` instead of `[Network].[Centre Id].Members`, as you used it. The difference is that my version excludes the `All` member, as it uses the members of the `Centre Id` **level**, while yours includes it, as it uses the members of the `Centre Id` **hierarchy**, which, assuming this is a standard attribute hierarchy, consists of the `All` member on the `All` level, and all bottom level members on the `Centre Id` level. And I assume you do not want to include the `All` member in the calculation of the top 25 percent, but just the single centers.

As you see, I several times mentioned some of the concepts that are crucial to understanding MDX: data types (member, tuple, set, level, hierarchy), and context.

Comment: @frankPI you use `TAIL` in the first custom measure with just one argument - what does this function do with only one arg?

Comment: infact is `TopPercent` delivers the data sorted why use `TAIL` at all - is not `.Item(0).Item(0)` sufficient?

Comment: @whytheq As the documentation of Tail (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146056.aspx) states, Tail with one argument is equivalent to `Tail(, 1)`. As Item(0) returns the first tuple of the set, while we need the last, we cannot omit it. We could, however, use `TopPercent(...).Item(TopPercent(...).Count - 1).Item(0)`. But then, we would to have repeat the `TopPercent` expression twice (or introduced a named set for it). I am not sure if that would be a gain in clarity or performance, however.

Comment: @FrankPI thanks. I'm back re-visiting `MDX` again (still not confident that this language will ever become intuitive to me ....will keep banging my head again the brick wall and maybe some stuff will sink in!)

Comment: @FrankPI perfect example of how I always underestimate this language - think something is going to be easy and 2hrs later I'm still scratching my head: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344633/previous-equivalent-mtd-across-multiple-months